# Routing issue for Laravel API hosted in Amezon linux 2 AMI, Shows 403 not found error

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-linux-2

I hosted my application developed using react and laravel in a VPS and its working over there. Now i am trying to move that app from VPS to Amazon EC2 with amazon linux 2 AMI OS and uploaded API developed using Laravel. Laravel is working and gives welcome page. But when i tried to browse through postman for particular API it gives me 403 not found error pls help to fix this

Comment: Its solved, setting "allowoverride All" was not added in httpd config file. To edit config file we need to use sudo command

Comment: Could you provide your solution as an answer for better visibility? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here I was editing httpd config file but permission denyed. Later I checked cofig file was not edited. Then I Changed permission of config file to 777 and edited and added "allowoverride All". It solved my problem.